# How to unselect layers in layerswitcher and save in variable only the selected ones

Tags: openlayers, layer, arrays

Thanks to Richard Greenwood, this function shows which layer is unselected in the layerswitcher control.

```
map.events.register('changelayer', null, function(evt){
       if(evt.property === "visibility") {
          alert(evt.layer.name + " layer visibility changed to " + evt.layer.visibility );
       }
});
```

I'm wondering how I can save in a variable array the unselected layers. For instance I have layers "a", "b", "c" in the layerswitcher, so "a" is unselected and I want "b" and "c" saved in an array like myarray = [b,c]. Then, I can loop over this array to do some processes calling only layers "b" and "c".

I'll appreciate some ideas about this, thanks in advance,

Comment: This is a general JavaScript programming question, and should have been posted to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```js
var vlayers = [];
function get_vlayers(){
  vlayers = [];    
  for (var i=0; i<map.layers.length; i+=1) {
    if (map.layers[i].visibility) {
      vlayers.push(map.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}
map.events.register('changelayer', null, get_vlayers)
```